# How to write a validation for exactly 3 digits in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

In my controller I have this :

```
validates_presence_of :order_of_importance, :on => :create, :with => /^\d{3}$/
```

But this would still validate ( *i think* ), if they typed :

```
4231
```

But I want to make sure they **only** type in 3 digit characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/^\d{3}$/` should do it. It makes sure that the digits start and end at the ends of the string to match.

Also, you don't need the `i` at the end, since digits aren't cased.

Comment: Hmm.. actually that didn't seem to validate.

Comment: Is there anything besides the number? Even whitespace would mess this up. The regex will match if there are ONLY three digits. If you need "three digits in a string", try: `/(?:^|\D)\d{3}(?:\D|$)/`

Comment: What @Kolik wrote is right but you should use validates_format_of instead of validates_presence_of to use a regex

Comment: `/\A\d{5}\z/` rails doesn't like anchors like `^` and `$`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
validates_length_of :order_of_importance, :maximum => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps "more Railsy" way would be:

```
validates_length_of       :order_of_importance, :on => :create, :is => 3
validates_numericality_of :order_of_importance, :on => :create
```